# How to add a fix Linear Layout programmatically in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scroll

I need something like this:
LinearLayout (fix)
 - Button
LinearLayout
 - ScrollView
 - TextView 
 - TextView 
 - TextView

I want the first LinearLayout to be fix (like a header). When someone tries to scroll down, i want the TextView to go behind the fix LinearLayout. I want that button always to be visible. With this code, everything is scrolling down.
Here is my code:

```
    ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(linearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

    final LinearLayout topLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    topLinearLayout.setOrientation(topLinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    linearLayout.addView(topLinearLayout);

    final Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setText(R.string.button);
    topLinearLayout.addView(button);

    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText(R.string.title);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    linearLayout.addView(title);
```

Comment: You can create it as layout xml and then inflate it. That would be much easier to handle.  `LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayout, yourContainer, attachToRootOrNot);`

Comment: And how can i do that? Can you be more specific?

Comment: just create a layout for your view via layout editor or writing xml manually, then call it like I wrote up. Than call children views by for example  `Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.btn);`  Edit: You can check it out a video of my application at betone.co.uk . If one of the screens is like what you want to achieve I can share that part of code to you

Answer (score 0):

You are adding your `topLinearLayout` into your `linearLayout`, which you are adding in your `scrollView`. this is not you want.

add `scrollView` and `topLinearLayout` in another `LinearLayout`

```
final LinearLayout mainlinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
mainlinearLayout.setOrientation(linearLayout.VERTICAL);

ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);

final LinearLayout topLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
topLinearLayout.setOrientation(topLinearLayout.VERTICAL);

mainlinearLayout.addView(topLinearLayout); 
mainlinearLayout.addView(scrollView);

final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(linearLayout.VERTICAL);
scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

final Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText(R.string.button);
topLinearLayout.addView(button);

TextView title = new TextView(this);
title.setText(R.string.title);
title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
linearLayout.addView(title);
```

Comment: Thanks you, but it doesn,t work. I have this error: `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.alexm.iqtest/com.example.alexm.iqtest.IqTest}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Problem solved with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33754968/how-to-have-dynamically-a-fixed-header-with-scrollable-content-in-android)