# How to have dynamically a fixed header with scrollable content in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-scroll

I have created programmatically a `RelativeLayout` which contains a button. I have also created a `ScrollView` which contains a `LinearLayout` in which are more than 10 `TextViews`. I want to have the `RelativeLayout` to be aligned top and fixed. When someone tries to scroll down, i want all the `TextViews` to go behind the fixed `RelativeLayout`. I want that button to be always visible. With this code, the `RelativeLayout` and the button are not displayed. Where am i wrong?
RelativeLayout (fixed)
- Button
LinearLayout
- ScrollView
- TextView 
- + other 10 TextViews
Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
    this.setContentView(relativeLayout);

    final Button restartButton = new Button(this);
    restartButton.setText(R.string.restartButton);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    restartButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
    relativeLayout.addView(restartButton);

    ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    this.setContentView(scrollView);

    final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(linearLayout.VERTICAL);
    scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    testTitle.setText(R.string.text_view1);
    linearLayout.addView(textView1);

    // + other 10 text views
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you replace your RelativeLayout with ScrollView. Just set firstly some LinearLayout as contentView and then put there your RelativeLayout via `addView(relativeLayout)` and the put there you scrollView also via `addView(scrollView)`

EDIT:

your new code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final LinearLayout mainLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mainLinearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mainLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(mainLinearLayoutParams);
        mainLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        this.setContentView(mainLinearLayout);

        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
        mainLinearLayout.addView(relativeLayout);

        final Button restartButton = new Button(this);
        restartButton.setText(R.string.restartButton);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        restartButton.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);
        relativeLayout.addView(restartButton);

        ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
        mainLinearLayout.addView(scrollView);

        final LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(linearLayoutParams);
        linearLayout.setOrientation(linearLayout.VERTICAL);
        scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

        TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
        testTitle.setText(R.string.text_view1);
        linearLayout.addView(textView1);

        // + other 10 text views
    }
```

EDIT 2: renamed first linearLayout to mainLinearLayout according to the comment

Comment: Regarding your code, i renamed the first `linearLayout` with `mainLinearLayout` because there were 2 layouts with the same name. In the end, worked perfectly. Thank you so much!